# Maximum and Minimum of $\sin x + \cos x$ using Taylor series

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, inequality, taylor-expansion

It can be shown that the maximum and minimum values for $\sin x + \cos x$ are $+\sqrt2$ and $-\sqrt2$ respectively (e.g., using calculus, or writing as ${\sqrt2}\sin (x + \frac{\pi}{4})$).

I was wondering can anybody show a proof using the Taylor series exapansion of $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions:

$\sin x = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + \ldots$.

$\cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!} + \ldots$.

When we add these two series up, we get $(1+x) - (\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!}) + (\frac{x^4}{4!} + \frac{x^5}{5!}) \ldots$ . Can this series be shown to lie $\geq- \sqrt{2}$ and $\leq \sqrt{2}$?

Comment: I don't see a reason why the series would help.

Comment: Can you show directly from the Taylor series for $\sin x$ or $\cos x$ that the absolute value is never more than $1$? This attempt will be at least as hard as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a power series that goes through a complete cycle of sign changes every four terms. Another thing that goes through a complete cycle of sign changes every four terms is a geometric sequence with ratio $i$: $i^2 = -1$, $i^3 = -i$, $i^4 = 1$, $i^5 = i$.
And indeed, seeing a series based on sinusoidal functions,
it's natural to think this might have something to do with $e^{ix}$, where
$$
e^{ix} = 1 + ix - \frac{x^2}{2!} - i\frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + i\frac{x^5}{5!}
 - \frac{x^6}{6!} - i\frac{x^7}{7!} \pm\cdots .
$$

Multiply the series term by term by the constant $\sqrt2 e^{i\pi/4} = 1 + i$:

$$
\sqrt2 e^{i\pi/4}e^{ix} =
1 + i + ix - x  - \frac{x^2}{2!}  - i\frac{x^2}{2!} - i\frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^3}{3!}
 + \frac{x^4}{4!} + i\frac{x^4}{4!} + i\frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^5}{5!} \pm\cdots .
$$

At this point it's convenient to give this series a name.
Let $f(x) = \sqrt2 e^{i\pi/4}e^{ix} = \sqrt2 e^{i(x+(\pi/4))}$.
Then the imaginary part of $f(x)$ is

$$
\operatorname{Im}(f(x)) = 
 1 + x - \frac{x^2}{2!} - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} \pm\cdots ,
$$

which is exactly the Taylor series you want to find the range of.

Given that $x$ is real, we know that $x + \frac\pi4$ is real and therefore
$e^{i(x+(\pi/4))}$ is on the unit circle in the complex plane; that is,
its modulus is
$$ \left\lvert e^{i(x+(\pi/4))} \right\rvert = 1. $$

Therefore
$$ \lvert f(x) \rvert = \left\lvert \sqrt2 e^{i(x+(\pi/4))} \right\rvert = \sqrt2 . $$

The absolute value of the imaginary part of a complex number $z$ cannot be greater than the modulus of that number, $\lvert z\rvert$, so we have established that

$$
-\sqrt2 \leq \lvert \operatorname{Im}(f(x)) \rvert \leq \sqrt2.
$$

To show that the bounds $-\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt2$ are actually attained,
see what happens if you set $x = -\frac54\pi$ or $x = \frac\pi4$.

Granted, this is not a nice proof. Moreover, it's largely just a version of the $\sqrt2 \sin\left(x + \frac\pi4\right)$ method in disguise, with a lot of unnecessary extra work. And it gets to its (real-valued) conclusions via a detour through complex analysis. But I think it qualifies as a proof using the Taylor series.

Answer (score 1):

Let $c=\cos, s=\sin$. From the Taylor series you see that $c, s$ are smooth and $c'=s, s=c'$ and $c^2+s^2 = 1$ (differentiate and show the derivative is zero). Then $(c+s)^2+(c-s)^2 = 2$ from which you get $|c+s| \le \sqrt{2}$.